# Changing Lebesgue Integral to Riemann Integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I recently ran across this problem regarding the change from a Lebesgue integral to a Riemann integral.

Suppose $g$ is a continuous function from $[0, \infty)$ to $[0, \infty)$. with $g(0) = 0$ and the derivative function $g'$ is continuous in $(0, \infty)$. Suppose $f$ is non-negative and measurable on E.

How do I show $ \int_E g \circ f \,d\mu  =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \mu(E_t)g'(t) \,dt ?$ where $E_t$ is the set $\{x \in E : f(x) > t\}$.

Any help will be really appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{E}g(f(x))\,d\mu=\int_{E}\int_{0}^{f(x)}g'(t)\,dt\,d\mu $$.

$$=\int_{E}\int_{\Bbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{\{0\leq t< f(x)\}}g'(t)\,dt\,d\mu$$

Now by Tonelli's Theorem we have

$$\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{E}\mathbf{1}_{\{f(x)> t\geq 0\}}g'(t)\,d\mu \,dt=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{\{t\geq 0\}}\mu(E_{t})g'(t)\,dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu(E_{t})g'(t)\,dt$$.